# Issue with "didSelectRowAt indexPath" in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm pretty new to swift but I've managed to follow along for the most part. However, there's an issue with my code that the code itself can't even identity apparently(I'm not receiving any error signs). I'm trying to click on a row from the table view to make it go to the following page but I don't think the code is recognizing the didselectrow method. Maybe one of you more experienced persons can help me out.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class OnePercentersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource
{

    var copiedExecutiveArray : [String] = NSArray() as! [String]
    var identities : [String] = NSArray() as! [String]

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let copyExecutiveNames : ExecutiveArray = ExecutiveArray()
        copiedExecutiveArray = copyExecutiveNames.executiveNames
        identities = copyExecutiveNames.executiveNames
    }

    //how many sections in table
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    //returns int (how many rows)
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return copiedExecutiveArray.count
    }

    //contents of each cell
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")//UITableViewCell()
        let personName = copiedExecutiveArray[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = personName
        return cell!

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        let execName = identities[indexPath.row]
        let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: execName)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
        print("button clicked")
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: Not related but `var identities : [String] = NSArray() as! [String]` is horrible. Write simply `var identities = [String]()`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked other parts of your code, but to make `tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)` work, your ViewController needs to conform to `UITableViewDelegate`:

```
class OnePercentersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
```

Also you need to connect the `delegate` of the `UITableView` to your ViewController in your storyboard. Or you can do it in code, if you have an `@IBOutlet` to the `UITableView`. Anyway, not only `dataSource`, but also `delegate`.

---

And this is not a critical issue, but you can write the first two lines of the class as:

```
var copiedExecutiveArray : [String] = []
var identities : [String] = []
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a day and a half watching Youtube videos and reading comments to similar problems, tt took trial and error but I finally got it thanks to you guys!It finally clicked when I read that I had to connect the delegate to the ViewController through the storyboard, so thanks for that!

Here's the final code for those with similar issue:

```
    import UIKit
    import Foundation

    class OnePercentersViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
    {

var copiedExecutiveArray : [String] = []
var identities : [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let copyExecutiveNames : ExecutiveArray = ExecutiveArray()
    copiedExecutiveArray = copyExecutiveNames.executiveNames
    identities = copyExecutiveNames.executiveNames
}

//how many sections in table
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

//returns int (how many rows)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return copiedExecutiveArray.count
}

//contents of each cell
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) 
    let personName = copiedExecutiveArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = personName
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let execName = identities[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: execName)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
}



    }
```

Comment: How I can connect the delegate through the storyboard? :(